# C# MongoDB Driver: Can't find the way to run complex query for AnyIn filter in MongoDB

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a document like this:

```
{
  "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "groupsAuthorized": [
    "USA/California/SF",
    "France/IDF/Paris"
  ]
}
```

And I have an user that has a list of authorized groups, like for example the following:

```
"groups": [
  "France/IDF",
  "USA/NY/NYC"
]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to retrieve all documents in the database that the user is authorized to retrieve, essentially I want to be able to check in the list "groupsAuthorized" if one of the group contains a subset of an element of the other list "groups" contained in my user authorizations

using the following values:

```
my document:
{
  "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "groupsAuthorized": [
    "USA/California/SF",
    "France/IDF/Paris"
  ]
}

my user permissions:
"groups": [
  "France/IDF",
  "USA/NY/NYC"
]
```

the user should be able to retrieve this document as the string "France/IDF" is correctly contained in the string "France/IDF/Paris", however, if the values would've been like this:

```
my document:
{
  "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "groupsAuthorized": [
    "USA/California/SF",
    "France/IDF"
  ]
}

my user permissions:
"groups": [
  "France/IDF/Paris",
  "USA/NY/NYC"
]
```

it should not work, because my user is only authorized to view documents from France/IDF/Paris and USA/NY/NYC and none of the string inside of the authorizedGroups of my document contains those sequences

I've tried to use a standard LINQ query to achieve this which is fairly simple:

```
var userAuthorizedGroups = new List<string> { "France/IDF/Paris", "USA/NY/NYC" };
var results = collection.AsQueryable()
.Where(entity => userAuthorizedGroups
                .Any(userGroup => entity.authorizedGroups
                                  .Any(entityAuthorizedGroup => entityAuthorizedGroup.Contains(userGroup))));
```

But i'm getting the famous unsupported filter exception that it seems lot of people is having, i've tried different options found on the internet like the following:

```
var userAuthorizedGroups = new List<string> { "France/IDF/Paris", "USA/NY/NYC" };
var filter = Builders<PartitionedEntity<Passport>>.Filter.AnyIn(i => i.authorizedGroups, userAuthorizedGroups);
var results = (await collection.FindAsync(filter)).ToList();

return results;
```

But the problem is this will only check if one of the element of the array is contained inside the other array, It will not correctly work for case like "France/IDF" that should correctly match "France/IDF/Paris" because "France/IDF" string is contained inside the "France/IDF/Paris" string inside of my document

I'm getting a bit clueless on how to achieve this using the mongodb C# driver, i'm starting to think that I should just pull all documents to client and do the filtering manually but that would be quite messy

Has anyone an Idea on this subject ?

Comment: check [this](https://dev.to/djnitehawk/overcoming-the-limitations-of-mongodb-c-driver-1110) out for an alternative way to run complex queries with mongo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i'm starting to think that I should just pull all documents to client and do the filtering manually but that would be quite messy

don't do it :)

One place you can start with is [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/reference/driver/crud/linq/). It describes all the LINQ operators that are supported by the MongoDB .NET driver. As you can see `.Contains()` isn't mentioned there which means you can't use it and you'll get an arror in the runtime but it does not mean that there's no way to do what you're trying to achieve.

The operator closest to contains you can use is [$indexOfBytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfBytes/) which returns `-1` if there's no match and the position of a substring otherwise. Also since you need to match an array against another array you need two pairs of [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) and [$anyElementTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/index.html) to do exactly what .NET's `.Any` does.

Your query (MongoDB client) can look like this:

```
db.collection.find({
    $expr: {
        $anyElementTrue: {
            $map: {
                input: "$groupsAuthorized",
                as: "group",
                in: {
                    $anyElementTrue: {
                        $map: { 
                            input: ["France/IDF/Paris", "USA/NY/NYC"],
                            as: "userGroup",
                            in: { $ne: [ -1, { $indexOfBytes: [ "$$userGroup", "$$group" ] } ] }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gFIS7sHn5hg),

You can run the same query from .NET using `BsonDocument` class which takes a string (JSON) and converts into a query:

```
var query = BsonDocument.Parse(@"{
    $expr: {
        $anyElementTrue:
        {
            $map:
            {
                input: '$groupsAuthorized',
                    as: 'group',
                    in: {
                    $anyElementTrue:
                    {
                        $map:
                        {
                            input: ['France/IDF/Paris', 'USA/NY/NYC'],
                                as: 'userGroup',
                                in: { $ne: [-1, { $indexOfBytes: ['$$userGroup', '$$group'] } ] }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}");

var result = col.Find(query).ToList();
```

Comment: Your solution is very good and I was able to tweak it to fully fit my needs, would you know how to combine this with a previous IQueryable ?
I'm using a framework that expose an API to filter/sort/paginate using the IQueryable interface but I dont know how to combine the solution you've proposed me (using collection.Find with a bson document of my request) and my previous behaviour working with IQueryable

Comment: sorry i've miss-pressed enter button and the comment went of, you literally responsed in 50 seconds lol, i've edited my comment

Comment: @Rakiah you can't do it unfortunately. When you're trying to use LINQ and IQueryable you must have 1:1 coverage between MongoDB's Aggregation Framework operators and LINQ operators. In this case `.Contains()` is the missing piece of puzzle. So you have to use `.Find()`. One hint would be to use `nameof` operator in C# if you're concerned that any refactoring will break the query

Comment: Ah, I don't think I would know how to translate to the LINQ way, sadly, because i'm using a framework and have no control over it I can't neither remove the IQueryable system.
Would you have any hints if its even feasible to translate this:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/ihi19w_uU2l
into a LINQ way ?
the OR part would be quite easy but the expression itself seems impossible to me to be translated without using contains/startsWith/Any etc

Comment: @Rakiah no, this is not possible as for now because `$indexOfBytes` has no counterpart in LINQ

Comment: @Rakiah the way you need to think about LINQ for MongoDB is like you can write the same queries as for in-memory objects / SQL but the runtime needs to know how to translate them into MongoDB language because at the end of the day you need your operation to be executed in the database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214432/discussion-between-rakiah-and-mickl).

Comment: @mickl any idea of how I can do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65480659/how-to-run-complex-query-with-any-inside-any-mongodb-driver-c-sharp